# More performant way with jQuery to find nth cell in every table row based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

We have a table, that allows for an advanced search.  I'd like to get the table to highlight the text in the table of each term them searched for.  For example: if they searched for a specific word in the "subject" field, it should only highlight that term in the "subject" column even though that word might appear in another column.

I am using a highlighting plugin for the `.highlight()` method - but **I'm mostly worried about an efficient way to select the proper table cells.**  *What I have works*, but it's slow with several hundred rows.  I feel like there's a better way to do this without an `.each()` loop.

```
//Select the table
var $table = $("#myTable");

//Examples: The users' search terms
var sFrom = "example";
var sTo = "example";
var sSubject = "example";

//Make sure there is at least 1 term to search for
if(sFrom !== "" || sTo !== "" || sSubject !== ""){

    //Find the index of each column based on a class set on the table header
    //(the number of columns could change from page to page)
    var $headers = $table.find("thead tr").children();
    var iFrom = $headers.filter(".js-from").index();
    var iTo = $headers.filter(".js-to").index();
    var iSubject = $headers.filter(".js-subject").index();

    //----------------------------------------------
    //This is the critical part!
    //----------------------------------------------
    //Loop through each table row and select each 
    $table.find("tbody tr").each(function (i, row) {
        var $thisRowCells = $(row).children();
        if (sFrom !== "") $thisRowCells.eq(iFrom).highlight(sFrom);
        if (sTo !== "") $thisRowCells.eq(iTo).highlight(sTo);
        if (sSubject !== "") $thisRowCells.eq(iSubject).highlight(sSubject);
    });
    //----------------------------------------------
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here's a JSFiddle of the above code to try out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLTdf/1/

Comment: Is it possible you need to optimize your `.highlight()` method instead?

Comment: It's possible, but it's a pretty quick one as is.  You can check out the page I got it from here: http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Comment: The O'Reilly "jQuery Cookbook" suggests that replacing `.each()` with an ordinary `for` loop will bring some optimization (p.112).

Comment: @mblase75: Regular for loops are really anoying in JS though; The index variable has function scope and closures don't work.

Comment: @missingno I didn't say he should replace `.each()` with `for` in all cases; I said he should try it as an optimization in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me and be about 2x faster than the `.each()` loop when timed.  I was able to highlight 3 unique strings in seperate columns for 500 rows in ~200ms

```
var $headers = $table.find("thead th");
var iFrom = $headers.filter(".js-from").index()+1;
var iTo = $headers.filter(".js-to").index()+1;
var iSubject = $headers.filter(".js-subject").index()+1;

if (sFrom!== "") $table.find("tr td:nth-child("+iFrom+")").highlight(sFrom);
if (sTo!== "") $table.find("tr td:nth-child("+iTo+")").highlight(sTo);
if (sSubject!== "") $table.find("tr td:nth-child("+iSubject+")").highlight(sSubject);
```

Can this be improved at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to avoid looping, but you can trim down the size of the stack before you do it. Something like:

```
var input = $(e.currentTarget),
    index = input.parent().index(),
    needle = input.val().toLowerCase(),
    haystack = $("td:nth-child(" + (index+1) + ")");

haystack.each(function() {
    var td = $(this);

    if(td.text().toLowerCase().indexOf( needle ) != -1)
        td.highlight(needle);
    else
        td.highlight(needle);

});
```

(I've got a jsfiddle up at http://jsfiddle.net/nicholasstephan/84DK9/)

might work better...

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work because there are other cells besides the ones we are searching against.  Check out this jsfiddle I put together, I probably should have included this in the first place. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLTdf/

Answer (score 0):

IE8 did not survive the jsfiddle test. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLTdf/